# Copy table from Oracle DB to MS sql db

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am trying to copy a table from an oracle database to a microsft sql database. I used this link as [my guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a66736/ch63.htm) and am using Visual Studio 2012. I keep getting `ORA-00900`: invalid SQL statement. 
Any help will be appreciated.

```
 void populateData()
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(WebPhoneConnString());
        conn.Open();
                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandText = "SqlBulkCopy from name/password@SID- to name/password@dataSource- replace ALL_WEB_PHONE_VIEW_N using SELECT * FROM ALLWEBPHN_N_MV";

                DataTable DT = null;
                OracleDataAdapter adap = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
                adap.Fill(DT);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you are coding this in dot.net?

Does this have to be done on a regular basis?

If not, use the Import/Export tool. A couple clicks later creates a SSIS package under the hood and moves the data from Oracle to SQL Server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

Please note, everything in Oracle needs the client library for Oracle installed on the machine facilitating the exchange.

Comment: "*everything in Oracle needs the client library for Oracle installed* - that's not entirely true. If you use Java/JDBC you only the JDBC driver, no Oracle client is needed then.

Comment: But I never use JDBC, I do not like coffee!  Good info.

Comment: No, this doesn't need to be done on a regular basis. We had a link server set up that was handling all of this until the Oracle db was moved. While we wait for permission for the link server to access the new DB, we need to pull into SQL server a copy of one of the tables. I will try the import/export tool.

Comment: The import/export tool is the way to go for ad-hoc data movement.